# How to convert a javascript object to DyanamoDb JSON format?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

`JSON.stringify(obj)` converts the object into normal JSON format.

How to convert a javascript object to DyanamoDb JSON format ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This library does exactly what I wanted to do:

"Translates sane javascript objects (and JSON) into DynamoDb format and vice versa."

https://www.npmjs.com/package/dynamodb-marshaler

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "DynamoDB JSON format".

JSON, is JSON, but here is an example of putting a JSON object into DynamoDB:

```
  Document doc = Document.FromJson( itemJson );
  table.PutItem( doc);
```